# Can anyone help me with my TigerVNC xstartup script for Ubuntu 18.04's GNOME dock icon's missing issue?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, xorg, remote-desktop, vnc

Basically, I do not totally understand how GNOME the whole stuff works.

As the title shows, I am currently working on using [TigerVNC](https://tigervnc.org/) to start a GNOME desktop, which is separate from the original GNOME when I use a physical screen to log in.

[Here is my physical desktop appearance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXFdv.png)

Here is my `~/.vnc/xstartup` script (`xstartup`):
And I ran it by `vncserver -verbose -localhost yes :2`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Change "GNOME" to "KDE" for a KDE desktop, or "" for a generic desktop
MODE="GNOME"

#Uncommment this line if using Gnome and your keyboard mappings are incorrect.
# export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1

# Load X resources (if any)
if [ -e "$HOME/.Xresources" ]
then
        xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
fi

export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu

# Try a GNOME session, or fall back to KDE
if [ "GNOME" = "$MODE" ]
then
        if which gnome-session >/dev/null
        then
                # see /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session for more info
                dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu --debug &
        else
                MODE="KDE"
        fi
fi

# Try a KDE session, or fall back to generic
if [ "KDE" = "$MODE" ]
then
        if which startkde >/dev/null
        then
                startkde &
        else
                MODE=""
        fi
fi

# Run a generic session
if [ -z "$MODE" ]
then
        xsetroot -solid "#DAB082"
        x-terminal-emulator -geometry "80x24+10+10" -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
        x-window-manager &
fi
```

[Notice there are two icons missing on the left (one is Terminal app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4ChP.jpg)

I am a newbie to the whole GNOME stuff.

Hope someone can give me some suggestions!

---

I have also tried replace `dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu --debug &` with `dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-shell &`.

It turned out the icons were back, but my `Settings` window was blank.

[The left side icons were back but Settings' windows was blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJudY.jpg)

The error message from `tigervnc`:

```
Thu Jan 28 22:13:02 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5902
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
GNOME Shell-Message: 22:13:02.986: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Gjs-Message: 22:13:03.130: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
Gjs-Message: 22:13:03.159: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspaceThumbnail.js 891]: reference to undefined property "_switchWorkspaceNotifyId"

(gnome-shell:15336): Bluetooth-WARNING **: 22:13:03.209: Could not create bluez object manager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.6794" (uid=1001 pid=15336 comm="gnome-shell " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=1025 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
GNOME Shell-Message: 22:13:03.384: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation

(gnome-shell:15336): AccountsService-WARNING **: 22:13:03.577: Could not get current seat: No data available
```

---

I have also followed the instructions in [Arch Linux-TigerVNC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC)
Namely, adding this file into `~/.vnc/config` and removing `xstartup` script.

```
session=ubuntu
geometry=1920x1080
localhost
alwaysshared
```

Unfortunately, my icons were still different from my original GNOME desktop :(

---

Here is my current theme:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
'Adwaita'
```

I don't know if this was caused by `Adwaita` icons.
For example, here is my `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=Use the command line
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/index.html
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-terminal
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.28.2
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-SingleWindow=false
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Actions=new-window
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal

NoDisplay=true

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
```

I found that `./Adwaita/scalable/apps/utilities-terminal-symbolic.svg` whose basename is not `utilities-terminal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I solved it by `apt install -y gnome-tweaks` and tweaked the `icon-theme` back to `Ubuntu-mono-dark` then my icons came back.
I found that the issue of missing icons is a **feature** for `Adwaita` icon-theme rather than a bug.

But I have never changed `org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme` to another theme.
I still wondered why `org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme` suddenly changed (And the changes only happened in my `gnome-session` viewed from my VNC viewer, while the physical GNOME was intact.)
(Perhaps because I `kill` the `gnome` process, causing all settings to become the default (`Awaita` seems like a default setting of gnome)?)

Answer (score 0):

The Gnome icon set available with the base Ubuntu desktop install is incomplete. Try installing the gnome-icon-theme package. I discovered this accidentally when setting up the Numix theme, which depends on some of the missing Gnome icons.